# Datetime formatting Python

Tags: python, datetime

I want to convert string into date time format. I have three different formats in my current column like this-

01-05-21 5:50 (month-day-year hour:min)
13/01/2021 05:50:00 (Day/month/year hour:min:sec)
1/1/21 0:00   (day/month/year hour:min)

I want to convert them into single format lets say 13-01-21 05:50:00 and 05-01-21 05:50:00 (day-month-year Hour:min:sec)

I can not able to do both the things in single python code.

df.head()

```
ts
```

0   01-05-21 5:50

1   01-05-21 6:00

2   13/01/2021 05:00:00

3   13/01/2021 05:10:00

4   1/1/21 0:00

(Three different formats)

Comment: How do you know that 01-05-21 is month-day-year format (and vice versa)?

Comment: Are you using Pandas?

Comment: yes I am using pandas

Comment: Error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @anon01 yes I know these two formats because month cant exceed 12

Comment: That's not sufficient to determine the date, only to know that it's inconsistent.  How do you know if `05-01-2021` is in January or May?

Comment: @anon01 That's not a problem, because one date format uses dashes as the separator, the other forward slash.

Comment: @anon01 because there are more than 15000 entries. I saw them in excel and noted down different formats

Answer (score 0):

https://stackabuse.com/how-to-format-dates-in-python/

Use this link. You can add a hyphen between the number yourself

Answer (score -1):

You may use `to_datetime` here to conditionally choose between one of the two formatting masks, when converting the string column to datetime:

```py
df[df["df_str"].str.contains(r'^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{1,2}:\d{2}$')]["dt"] = pd.to_datetime(data["df_str"], format='%m-%d-%y %H:%M')
df[not df["df_str"].str.contains(r'^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{1,2}:\d{2}$')]["dt"] = pd.to_datetime(data["df_str"], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @RajeshMORE My synatax is off, but not my approach.  Try the updated version, or see if you can make it work.

Comment: Thank you. your code is working but encountered one more format in column. can you suggest me generic code so that I can mold it for more than 3 formats in column. (Can you please go through updated question) Thanks in Advance Tim

Comment: You need to just add logic to cover the new format.